# $resource service and controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a code like this:

```
angular.module( 'APPLICATION', ['ngResource'] )

    .service( 'Service', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
      var Model = $resource( 
          '/:node/:key.json', 
          { node: '@node', key: '@key' }, 
          { 
            query: {method: 'GET', isArray: false}
          }
      );
      var responseMessage, responseData;
      var successHandler = function (resource) {
        responseMessage = { success: resource.result.message };
        responseData = resource.result.data;
      };
      var errorHandler = function (resource) {
        responseMessage = { error: resource.headers().message };
      };

      this.model = null;
      this.fetch1 = function () {
        var result = Model.query( {node: this.model.node} );
        return result;
      };

      this.fetch2 = function () {
        var result = Model.query( {node: this.model.node} );
        result.$promise.then( successHandler, errorHandler );

        return responseData;
      };
    }] )

    .controller( 'Controller', ['$scope', 'Service', function ($scope, Service) {
      Service.model = $scope.model;

      // works
      var response = Service.fetch1();
      response.$promise.then( function (response) {
        $scope.items = response.result.data;
      } );

      // doesn't work
      $scope.items = Service.fetch2();
    }] );
```

How can I make **Service.fetch2** work?

I want to process data inside of the Service, not in the Controller, but I can't figure out how to send the data to the Controller once it's processed...

Comment: fetch2 returns undefined

Comment: What should it return?

Comment: it should return resource.result.data, once it arrives (it's assigned in successHandler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your fetch2 call also is async in nature you cannot do a direct assignment, as the results may not be available at that time. Return a promise from fetch2 as well. Like this

```
this.fetch2 = function () {
        var result = Model.query( {node: this.model.node} );
        return result.$promise.then( successHandler, errorHandler );
      };

  var successHandler = function (resource) {
        responseMessage = { success: resource.result.message };
        responseData = resource.result.data;
        return responseData;
      };
      var errorHandler = function (resource) {
        responseMessage = { error: resource.headers().message };
        return responseMessage;
      };
```

In your controller

```
Service.fetch2().then(function(data) {
  $scope.items=data;
});
```

Comment: seams to be working. gonna check if other http methods work as well.. Thanks!